# Is it possible to purchase or rent a book from Google Books?

Tags: google-books, google-play-store, google-play, google-play-books

There's a rare book on Google Books which is out-of-print and unavailable in online stores. The book is copyrighted, so it's not available on [archive.org](https://archive.org/) or similar sites. From a search on [worldcat](https://www.worldcat.org/), it also appears that the book is only housed in a few universities which are very far away from me. However, the book is scanned on Google Books and a preview is available for about a third of the book. It seems to be the only place online which has the book.

Is it possible for me to purchase or rent the book from Google? I see that Google has a service called ["Google Play Books"](https://play.google.com/store/books) which is recommended on the sidebar of Google Books, but even after I've favorited the book and added it to my wishlist, I still can't see it on Google Play to purchase or rent the ebook. Is this even possible to do? I simply want to read the whole book from Google Books, but I see no way to [purchase](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/185545?hl=en) or even [rent](https://play.google.com/store/books/theme/promotion_1001a15_textbooks?hl=en_US&gl=US) it.

Comment: Did you find it in play store?

Comment: @TheMaster No, I originally found this book on Google Books, but I thought that after favoriting it or adding it to my wishlist, that it would also show up in Google Play. But it hasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possibility to buy a book on Google Books depends on the book. For those that are available to be purchased in Google Books there is a red "BUY EBOOK" button. This button will open the book's listing in Google Play Books.

(I just confirmed that by searching in Google Books one of the featured books on Google Play Books).

It's worthy to mention that Google Books main goal is not to sell books, it's to be an index of all the books available some way, by the other hand Google Play Books main goal is commercially distribute books.

Another thing worthy to note is that it's possible to request a book from "remote" libraries through some local libraries. The best might be to contact your closest library.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the name, Google Books has nothing to do with Google play books. They're separate and different products by Google. You will not find the book you added to wishlist in Google Books in Google play books. It's like searching for spreadsheet saved inside Google sheets in Google slides.

Comment: Certain books listed in Google Books have a BUY EBOOK button that points to the Google Play Books listing (see [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161882/88163))

Comment: Hmm, it's too bad Google confuses users and makes them think they're related products by lumping them together on the sidebar. They really ought to be more clear about this distinction.